# Why is alignment imporant?

Tags: byte, alignment, cpu

I know that some processors fail with misaligned data, and others like the oh-so-common x86, would just be slower with that.

My question is why? Why is it harder for an x86 processor to get the data from the pointer `0x12345679` than it is from the pointer `0x12345678`? Just to be clear, I'm aware that page faults may happen if the data is in multiple pages, and I understand that more data may need to be fetched from memory (one part for the start of the value and one for the end), but that isn't always true and this isn't what my question is about. I'm asking, why is it always slower?

Suppose the memory starts at `0x10000000`. Why is it harder for the processor to get a 2-byte `short` from `0x10000001` than it is from `0x10000002`? Why is it harder to get a 4-byte `int` from `0x10000001` than it is from `0x10000000`? And so forth.

Comment: Do you know about cache lines and pre-fetching too?

Comment: Perhaps because memory accesses of the same size can't overlap then. But on the other hand memory accesses of different sizes still can overlap, so I don't know why it gains that much.

Comment: And it's not only page-faults but cache faults, and cache lines are typically much smaller(AFAIK 64 bytes are typical) than pages. But that still doesn't explain the behavior within a cache-line.

Comment: @Oderd, @CodeInChaos: Yes, I know of them. Page faults is just the most commonly spoken-of - and none of these actually explain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The processor can only access memory in an aligned fashion. This is a consequence of how the interconnect between the processor and memory functions.

When a processor supports unaligned reads, what's really happening is the processor issuing two separate reads (or one read of larger size) and stitching the parts together, which is why it's slower than an aligned read.

Comment: But why are processor and memory(cache I guess) connected in such a way? If no cache-line boundary is crossed the fetching the data from RAM isn't any more expensive, so it must be the cache access.

Comment: And if I have an unaligned 32 bit read which doesn't cross a 64 bit boundary on a 64 bit processor, why should that be more difficult than an aligned read?

Comment: Processor design is all about compromises. It takes a lot of transistors and a lot of power to make unaligned reads as efficient as aligned reads, and the use-case is so uncommon that it's better to spend them elsewhere. EDIT: Especially if all you're going to get out of it is "unaligned reads are sometimes fast and sometimes slow depending on whether they fall entirely within a cache line or not".

Comment: Is the call the processor makes not "I'd like bytes 2, 3, 4 and 5 please"? It seems to me like the address needs to be passed fully, if only for the case of reading a single byte. So it needs a way to ask for byte number 2, and it's also able to ask for 4 bytes - why can't it ask for the 4 bytes starting at 2, and can only do that for the 4 bytes starting at 0 or 4? (Note that I'd completely ignoring cache lines here as well. Assume I'm only ever going to access the first 32 bits of RAM for this theoretical question.)

Comment: Nope. When the memory is operating in single-byte mode, the processor goes "gimme byte 0; gimme byte 1; gimme byte 2; gimme byte 3" (four separate operations). Alternatively, it can operate in burst mode, where the processor says "gimme byte [0-3]" and the memory will send *all four* of those bytes. (The memory groups are *always* aligned, because otherwise you're really screwing up your cache lines). This means that if you go for an unaligned access, the processor has to issue two separate block requests and stitch them together.

Comment: -1, this answer doesn't explain why don't processors support unaligned reads, AKA what is a cache-line, etc...

Answer (score 4):

Because the data bus is wider than eight bits.

Let assume that the data bus is 32 bits. To get 16 bits from address 0x10000001, it has to get the four bytes that starts at 0x10000000 and shift the value to get the two bytes in the middle.

To get 16 bits from the address 0x10000003, it has to get the words that start at 0x10000000 and 0x10000004, and use one byte from each value.

Comment: Is the 'bus size' the size of the name of the processor i.e. 64-bit processor has a 64 bit wide bus?

Comment: @unixman83: No, that is the internal machine word size, which doesn't have to be the same as any of the bus sizes. They are often the same, but the Pentium for example was a 32-bit processor with a 32-bit address bus and a 64-bit data bus.

Answer (score 1):

One example: if the databus is 32 bits and a 32 bit value is not on a 32 bit boundary, the bytes will have to be fetched in more than one operation and moved around to load the value properly into a processor register.